# Gradle - append to system path from a task

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

How can I add a directory to my system path for subsequent tasks to execute properly?

This is my current attempt, but the PATH variable does not seem to change or persist :

```
task sourceEnv(type: Exec){
    environment "PATH", "$System.env.PATH" + System.getProperty("path.separator") +
        "$projectDir/src/dist/util"
}

task otherTask {
    dependsOn sourceEnv
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a global path outside the first task (in the `ext` namespace) and reuse it in both tasks.

```
ext.execPath = "$System.env.PATH" + System.getProperty("path.separator") + "$projectDir/src/dist/util"

task taskA(type: Exec){
    environment "PATH", execPath
    ...
}

task taskB(type: Exec){
    environment "PATH", execPath
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: This worked for me after I changed `ext.path` to `ext.execPath` (or any other previously undefined name). `path` is arleady defined in tasks and it gives you the Gradle task path.

I edited your answer to include the correction.